# How can I charge a 11,1 volt LiPo akku?

Tags: arduino, power, lithium-polymer

I didn't found any modules to charge my [11,1 volt LiPo akku](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00FY2URC0/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=556245207&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B005EPV0Y6&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_r=K07V2ANNG3VMBEKKZDGV), only for 3,7 volt with 5 volt power supply. How can I handle that with a micro-USB connector on my robotplatform?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? You have an 11.1 volt, 5000mAh battery pack. That is, you have a (11.1*5)V-Ah battery pack, or a 55.5 Wh battery pack.

A micro USB connector can [safely pass 9W of power](https://techpinions.com/why-apple-couldnt-go-to-micro-usb-charging/10212), meaning it would take (55.5Wh/9W) = 6h10m to charge, assuming you could perfectly utilize all of that power.

You should consider instead either:

1. Take the batteries out of the vehicle to charge, or
2. Put a proper battery charger on your vehicle and use a different connector than micro USB.

I'll warn you that LiPo batteries are [notorious](https://www.google.com/search?q=hoverboard%20fire) for [catching fire](https://www.google.com/search?q=cell+phone+fire) if they are [not properly charged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCWdnjLqVWw).

There are [plenty](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/sep/a-designers-guide-to-lithium-battery-charging) of [integrated circuits](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/674) that will [charge a LiPo battery](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-charger-ic-products.page), but again, I don't think you'll find one that simultaneously uses a micro USB input format to charge a battery of the style that you have because it would take so long.

Trying to hack your own circuit together to get what you want is needlessly dangerous.